# Procedure for showing a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f(x) = x^5 − 6x^2 + 21x + 13$

What is the procedure for showing $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: One approach is to show that this polynomial has no rational roots. Then you know that the polynomial has to be of the form $2\text{degree}\cdot 3\text{degree}$. Using this you could (possibly) reach a contradiction. However, this problem is a bit difficult as the normal reductions wont work. If you change 13 to 12 however..

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x) = p(x) q(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, where we can take $p$ and $q$ monic and non-constant. Use subscript $l$ to indicate taking coefficients mod $l$. Note that $\deg p_l(x) = \deg p(x)$, etc., and $f_l(x) = p_l(x) q_l(x)$.

One computes
$$ f_2(x) = x^5+x+1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1) $$
$$ f_3(x) = x^5 + 1 = (x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) $$

The factors of $f_2(x)$ have no roots, so are irreducible. The quartic factor of $f_3(x)$ also has no root, so if it factors, it's the product of monic irreducible quadratics. The quadratics must have discriminant $-1$ since otherwise they would factor with the quadratic equation, hence we get factors of the form $x^2+bx+c$ where $b^2-c = -1$. The possible quadratics are $x^2+1$, $x^2+x-1$, $x^2-x-1$, and no two of these give the quartic as product, so the quartic is irreducible

Hence the degrees of $p$ and $q$ are ($2$ and $3$ from $l=2$) and ($1$ and $4$ from $l=3$), a contradiction, so $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Maybe you can find a less computational way to show the quartic is irreducible....

Comment: +1 but I think $f_2(x) =  (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks, I've fixed it. Must have copied it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following arguments
$f$ does not have an integer root so there is no linear factor of f and alsothere is no factore of degree. If f is not irreducible then
$$x^5-6\,x^2+21\,x+13=\\
\left(x^2+a\,x+b\right)\,\left(x^3+c\,x^2+d\,x+e\right)=\\
x^5+\left(c+a\right)\,x^4+\left(d+a\,c+b\right)\,x^3+\left(e+a\,d+b
 \,c\right)\,x^2+\left(a\,e+b\,d\right)\,x+b\,e$$
We have $c=-a$ because the coefficient of $x^4$ vanishes.

So we get
$$x^5-6\,x^2+21\,x+13=\\
x^5+\left(d+b-a^2\right)\,x^3+\left(e+a\,d-a\,b\right)\,x^2+\left(a
 \,e+b\,d\right)\,x+b\,e
$$

$b$ must be a factor of $13$ so we have only four possible pairs for $(b,e)$. We can enlist all possible values for a,b,d,e. 
None of these quadruples will fit for the coefficient of power 3 and 1

$$
\begin{array}{ r | r | r | r | r | r | r  }
b\mid 13  &  e=\frac{13}{6}  &  -6-e  &  a \mid (-6-e)  &  d = \frac{-6-e}{a}+b &  d+b-a^2  &  ae+bd \\
\hline{}
-13  &  -1  &  -5  &  -5  &  -12  &  -50  &  161 \\
-13  &  -1  &  -5  &  -1  &  -8  &  -22  &  105 \\
-13  &  -1  &  -5  &  1  &  -18  &  -32  &  233 \\
-13  &  -1  &  -5  &  5  &  -14  &  -52  &  177 \\
-1  &  -13  &  7  &  -7  &  -2  &  -52  &  93 \\
-1  &  -13  &  7  &  -1  &  -8  &  -10  &  21 \\
-1  &  -13  &  7  &  1  &  6  &  4  &  -19 \\
-1  &  -13  &  7  &  7  &  0  &  -50  &  -91 \\
1  &  13  &  -19  &  -19  &  2  &  -358  &  -245 \\
1  &  13  &  -19  &  -1  &  20  &  20  &  7 \\
1  &  13  &  -19  &  1  &  -18  &  -18  &  -5 \\
1  &  13  &  -19  &  19  &  0  &  -360  &  247 \\
13  &  1  &  -7  &  -7  &  14  &  -22  &  175 \\
13  &  1  &  -7  &  -1  &  20  &  32  &  259 \\
13  &  1  &  -7  &  1  &  6  &  18  &  79 \\
13  &  1  &  -7  &  7  &  12  &  -24  &  163
\end{array}
$$

A simpler way is to notice that $f(27)=14345113$  is prime.
An explanation is here: [Showing the polynomial $x^4 + x^3 + 4x + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568094/showing-the-polynomial-x4-x3-4x-1-is-irreducible-in-mathbbqx/568308#568308)

In school mathematic exercises often [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_criterion) can be used, but I don't see how it can be used here. If one changes the constant term from $13$ to $12$ one gets 
$$x^5-6\,x^2+21\,x+12$$
and Eisensteins's criterion can be applied immediately: Modulo the prime $3$ all the coefficients vanish except the coefficient of $x^5$, but the constant term $12$ does not vanish modulo $3^2$.

Comment: I'm a little confused. In your second factor $x^3 + cx^2 + 12x + 1$, why are you assuming the linear term is $12x$ and the constant term is $1$? I can only see that the constant must be one of $\pm 1, \pm 13$. Besides, if you assume this constant term is 1, then that forces $b = 13$, which makes much of your table irrelevant (though no less impressive)

Comment: @user115654: thank you. I worked whith  a cas (maxima). When I printed out the TeX string for the polynomials to paste them into this post I had already assigned values 12 and 1 to the symbols "d" and "e" (the last line in the table!). I corrected this error.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense! I do like the (theoretical) simplicity of this approach. +1